# How to style points in openlayers 4

Tags: javascript, styles, openlayers, point

I'm trying to style points in a vector source in OpenLayers 4.

I've defined a style:

```
var pStyle = new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          width: 6, color: [255, 0, 0, 1]
          })
});
```

and added the style in the layer definition

```
var pLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          features: [p]
        }),
        style: pStyle
});
```

Commenting the style definition makes the point appear on the map so I'm assuming the rest of the code is fine. But I can't get my point to appear in red on the map.

fiddle at: https://codepen.io/fundef/pen/VXKYjP

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This seems to do the trick 
` pStyle = new Style({
          image: new Circle({
            radius: 8,
            fill: new Fill({color: 'rgba(200, 200, 255, 0.3)'}),
            stroke: new Stroke({color: 'blue', width: 1})
          })
});`

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use `fill` and `stroke`

```
    var myStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'}),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: [255,0,0], width: 2
        })
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ol.style.icon` for that.

This is a example:

```
<script>

iconFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
          color: '#8959A8',
          crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
          src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/examples/data/dot.png'
        }))
      }));

<script>
```

Comment: thanks for the workaround, I could change all my points to icons and display a png, but I was really looking for a way to style points using stroke and fill.